# How do I retrieve a single cell from MySQL database using query and assigned it to a variable in Java Netbeans Apache

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

First I am going to try using query to retrieve the int min_stock single cell using the item description. Then put that value into a variable. I want to be able to have the variable minStock to be equal to a number. I want to use it to make operations in my program.

````
PreparedStatement cm = con.prepareStatement(checkMinimumStock);
ResultSet minS = cm.executeQuery("SELECT min_stock FROM items WHERE item_description = '"+item+"'"); 
            int minStock = minS.getInt("min_stock");```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are choose wrong way to use `PrepareStatment`.
you have two option to do :

1: 
`String sql = "SELECT min_stock FROM items WHERE item_description = ?";`
`PreparedStatement cm = con.prepareStatement(sql);`
`cm.setString(1, item);`
`ResultSet rs = cm.executeQuery();`

2: 
`String sql = "SELECT min_stock FROM items WHERE item_description = '" + item + "'";`
`ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);`

and then

`if (rs.next())`
    `int minStock = rs.getInt("min_stock");`
`else` 
   `//not found any match row in DB table`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String checkMinimumStock = "SELECT min_stock FROM items WHERE item_description = ? ";
PreparedStatement cm = con.prepareStatement(checkMinimumStock);
cm.setString(1,item);
ResultSet minS = cm.executeQuery();
if(minS.next()){
  int minStock = rs.getInt("min_stock");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`String checkMinimumStock = "SELECT min_stock FROM items WHERE item_description = ? ";`

Forgot to add this in the beginning of the code!

Comment: Please edit your question with this information. It's not an answer, so it should be up there. You always can edit your own questions.